# Don't have the needed software to perform this action?

Tags: hacker-experience

I'm trying to access the Internet in the game, I already have the root password...but whenever I press login that error message in the title appears. Am I missing something? I'm as fresh as a fish out of the sea with the game so I'm confused as to what is happening.

Comment: Did you do any of the tutorials?

Comment: I did, the basic hacking and the first tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

After you update or install a software it doesn't run until you run it click the cogwheel next to it.